# NSDateFormatter for this datestring

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How can I format this timestamp with NSDateFormatter.

`2013-09-30T06:20:00.000Z`

I've tried using

```
NSDateFormatter *railsFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[railsFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.'###Z"];
```

I've also tried

```
[railsFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.'###'Z'"];
```

as well as

```
[railsFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
```

But every time they turn up as `(null)`. I've looked on the unicode website for the date formatting techniques, but this was as good as I could get.

Comment: There are dozens of existing questions that cover that date format. You want `ss.SSS` for the seconds and fractional seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

> [railsFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.'SSSZ"];